# Route in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I am creating e-commerce website in CodeIgniter and I Have to prepare SEO friendly URL.

Currently My URL is:-

> abc.com/product/product_list/1/categoryName

- `product` is my controller
- `product_list` is my function name
- `1` = category id
- `categoryName` is my category Name

And I have to make like this:-

> abc.com/categoryName

I have to remove controller name as well as function name and one uri segment i.e., category id and show only category name.

How can I do this? Is this possible using `.htaccess` file?

Comment: It is possible but it will hurt yur other pages

Comment: How can I achieve SEO friendly URL.  
Can I create this url:-
[abc.com/controllerName/categoryName]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use route as:

```
$route["(:any)"] = "product/product_list/$1";
```

But issue is that it will hurt your other controllers like if you have page like

```
abc.com/contactus
```

It will call the `product/product_list/`. I suggest you to use route as:

```
$route["category/(:any)"] = "product/product_list/$1";
```

You can use URL like:

```
abc.com/category/yourCatName
```

And get category name in controller by using **[`CI Segments`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)**.

**[CI Routes](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)**

Comment: In above case I have to take category Name unique and with the help of name I can take category Id and soo on .Am i Right..?

Comment: @RiteshPaliwal: if its work, please accept the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @RiteshPaliwal: not asking for vote just for accepting the answer by click on the left tick below the voting arrows.